# Push Notification issue. (With Firebase FCM) - IOS - Unity

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am quite new to iOS development and currently working on an app using Unity. I have encountered an issue that has been bothering me for the past couple of days. The mobile app I'm working on should receive push notifications, but it seems to have stopped working a few months ago.

Here are the details:
I am using Unity 2020.3.8f1 and the latest Firebase SDK 11.0.0. On my Mac, I have Xcode 14.3 installed.

In the Xcode project settings under "Unity-iPhone - Signing & Certs," I have enabled Push Notifications and Background Modes with Background Fetch and Remote Notifications selected.

I have also added the UserNotifications.framework in the General settings of the Xcode project.

I have allowed Xcode to handle automatic signing for the app.

Every time I build the app as an .ipa or for TestFlight and launch it, I receive the following error: "FCM: Failed to register for remote notifications."

I have already created an APN key on the Apple Developer portal, and it is uploaded to the Firebase project settings.

Interestingly, I have another app with the same setup where everything works fine all the time.

I suspect that the issue might be related to certificates. A few months ago, the development certificate for this app expired. When I received this Mac from a previous developer who quit, there was no .cerRequestSigning file available. Therefore, I generated a new one using Keychain Access and created a certificate using that new request file.

I'm not sure if this lead is accurate, but I find the certificate system in Apple quite confusing at the moment. Do any of you have any ideas where to look for a solution in my case?"

Both apps works fine on Android.